# Check whether a row or range of rows is locked in a table for MySql database?

Tags: java, mysql, locking

From java using MySql database, how can check whether a row or range of rows is locked in a table ?

Comment: You mean a check if table is locked?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a table is locked then you can try like this:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES
```

but you cannot check if a range of rows is locked.

You can also make it specific for a particular table like this:

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE `Table` LIKE '[YOURTABLENAME]' 
AND `Database` LIKE '[YOURDATABASENAME]' AND In_use > 0;
```

As per my opinion when a table is locked then the rows are locked automatically.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL uses only table-level locking. If you want row level locking capabilities, switch to InnoDB(A suggestion not a must).

Comment: `InnoDB` is a database engine used by `MySQL`, so your answer isn't exactly correct.

Comment: @Kayaman You are correct, I should add somewhere to the answer about the MyISAM Storage Engine. But obviously the user seems to be using InnoDB engine.